# Two if Statements, Why is One Not Executing?

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, switch-statement

I have two if statements and my project sees one and not the other. Here is the code:

```
If (IsPostBack) Then
  HandleUploadedFile()
End If

Dim savePath As String = "Images\ "

If (fileUpload.HasFile) Then
  Dim fileName As String = fileUpload.FileName
  savePath = Server.MapPath(savePath) + fileName
  fileUpload.SaveAs(savePath)
  Me.Label1.Text = "Your file was saved as " & fileName
  adp.Insert(fileUpload.FileName)
  Me.Label1.Text = "You did not specify a file to upload."
End If
```

When I trace my code I find it goes to the second if and then go to end if without running the code inside the conditional.

Comment: please reformat your question so it's easier to read.

Comment: It'd be nice if you formatted code—it's pretty hard to read in this form.

Comment: If (IsPostBack) Then
            HandleUploadedFile()
            Dim savePath As String = "Images\"

Comment: I have edited my answer to contain what I believe is the functionality you are after. The second if block actually looks like an implementation for a HandleUploadedFile subroutine. Try it and see if it works as you expect it to.

Answer (score 1):

What's happening in HandleUploadedFile?

If an error isn't trapped - you might fall right out of your routine (never reaching the second if).

If fileUpload is not declared... same scenario.

When you step through do you see it jumping to the end?

Edit:  Will you really have a file upload when the page has NOT been posted back? Maybe you really mean to put the entire code block in the If IsPostBack code block?

Edit2:
You could just add:

```
Public Sub HandleUploadedFile
```

above this line:

```
Dim savePath As String = "Images\ "
```

And add:

```
End Sub
```

below this line:

```
End If
```

Comment: OH yes - I also meant to mention (but dare not edit my answer again) that you should probably kill the trailing space in the value you are assigning to savePath or you will be trying to track another issue down.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I'm understanding the question correctly, but are you sure that fileUpload.HasFile is true?